# Detecting a keypress on a paper

Tags: jointjs

I have a diagram that looks great and wanted to add a zoom in and out capability bound to the "+" and "-" keys.  I added a `keydown` event handler to the `<div>` that is the container for the paper but that isn't being triggered with keypresses.   This makes me think that my recipe is wrong.  Has anyone tried to capture key strokes within a diagram and have a recipe to share?

The code that I tried was:

```
$(paperContainer).keydown(function(event) {
    console.log("Key press: %O", event);
});
```

where `paperContainer` is the jQuery object for my `<div>` that is correctly showing the diagram.  The `paperContainer` was created with:

```
var paperContainer = $("<div style='width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;'>");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by adding the event listener on the document:

```
$(document).on('keydown',function(){//your implementation})
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, I'm not sure if you're properly attaching to the Div element. Try $(".paperContainer") if it's a class, otherwise $("#paperContainer") to grab the div if has an ID.

If that doesn't work, check things out in chrome, and jump into the console.

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the response.  Ive updated my question showing how paperContainer was built.  It is a jQuery object that contains a DIV that is the container for the JointJS diagram.  No errors are reported in the browsers and everything works as expected with the exception that keydown events are not being reported from the JointJS diagram.

Comment: According to the jquery docs, keydown will only be called on focused elements. I don't think you can call this function unless the item is focused and registers a keydown.

Comment: That's a good thought.  In my page, I added a textbox and gave it focus.  I saw that it was hilighted as expected.  Next I clicked in the diagram and saw the "removal" of the hilighting.  I am quite prepared to believe that the JointJS diagram doesn't have focus ... but then I am at a loss as to what does?

Comment: You could use document.activeElement to check and see what is the focused element.

Comment: Nice thinking!!  I added a keydown handler to "document" and dumped the complete event when a key is pressed.  It seems that when I give "focus" to the JointJS diagram, the keydown event appears as coming from the root "body" element.  This explains why my DOM keydown isn't getting called when the diagram has focus but leaves me with the original problem of how to detect keypresses on JointJS documents.

Comment: Ahh, well in this case you should use keypress (not keydown).

Comment: Sorry ... I wasn't been clear.  I used key press in the English language sense and not the DOM event sense.  Whether I detect keypress or keydown (DOM events), if I try and attach them to a handler associated with the JointJS document, they are lost because focus seems to have gone to body.  I can't capture key presses for the whole page as there are also text input fields.  My hope was that JointJS would get focus and propagate events on it to my handler.